# How can i pick image from multiple installed app not only camera or gallery in flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, imagepicker

In the app when user click the button then user can select any one app from installed app(which support image) and pick image from it and show it in imageview

like this but having gallery,photos and other installed app (pic 1)

[image]

when user tap on button this open and user select any installed app and pick image and show it in imageview in app

I tried document_picker and file_picker and result is Pic 2

[image]

I want bottom sheet open as default os like "pic1" but I get result (pic 2)

I don't know how to do it in flutter so please give some suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Try the file_picker plugin:

https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker

"Load files from cloud files (GDrive, Dropbox, iCloud)"

If you only want images to be selected use this

```
allowedExtensions: ['jpg', 'png'],
```

Comment: you know about flutter_document_picker, is this allow user to pick image from installed apps

Comment: Yes you can pick from almost everywhere on your device

Comment: Yes, but the most efficient way is to test it for yourself and see if it works.

Comment: I tried but i want bottom sheet open like android intent action and I get result as pic 2 as per the answer